# mysql inner join return null value,

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT `mpeda_fish`.`id`, `mpeda_fish`.`fish` as analysis, sum(mpeda_fishdetails.quantity) as qty
FROM (`mpeda_fishdetails`)
INNER JOIN `mpeda_scientificfish` ON `mpeda_scientificfish`.`id` = `mpeda_fishdetails`.`scientificfish`
INNER JOIN `mpeda_fish` ON `mpeda_fish`.`id` = `mpeda_scientificfish`.`fish`
INNER JOIN `mpeda_fishcatch` ON `mpeda_fishcatch`.`id` = `mpeda_fishdetails`.`fishcatch`
INNER JOIN `mpeda_harbour` ON `mpeda_harbour`.`id` = `mpeda_fishcatch`.`harbour`
WHERE `mpeda_fishcatch`.`status` =  1
ORDER BY `mpeda_fishdetails`.`id` ASC
```

this query gets 2 columns null value and one column gets data inside why?

Comment: You have used SUM function in your query but i am not able to see any Group by Clause.

Answer (score 0):

You use the SUM() function. In order to get meaningful results you should have a group by clause.

```
SELECT `mpeda_fish`.`id`, `mpeda_fish`.`fish` as analysis, sum(mpeda_fishdetails.quantity) as qty
FROM (`mpeda_fishdetails`)
INNER JOIN `mpeda_scientificfish` ON `mpeda_scientificfish`.`id` = `mpeda_fishdetails`.`scientificfish`
INNER JOIN `mpeda_fish` ON `mpeda_fish`.`id` = `mpeda_scientificfish`.`fish`
INNER JOIN `mpeda_fishcatch` ON `mpeda_fishcatch`.`id` = `mpeda_fishdetails`.`fishcatch`
INNER JOIN `mpeda_harbour` ON `mpeda_harbour`.`id` = `mpeda_fishcatch`.`harbour`
WHERE `mpeda_fishcatch`.`status` =  1
GROUP BY `mpeda_fish`.`id`, `mpeda_fish`.`fish`
ORDER BY `mpeda_fishdetails`.`id` ASC
```